# php array_push causing server 500

Tags: php, array-push

Is there another way to write this array looping code. I seem to get a server 500 error when I run the code which I cant seem to understand. It specifically occurs on the the array_push line. Any help guidance on rewriting the statement without using the array_push would help me.

```
$PaymentOrderItems = array();

foreach($resultBookings->getRecords() as $key=>$record_row) {
   $Item = array(
    'name' => $record_row->getField('Start_date'),
    'desc' => $record_row->getField('Description'),
    'amt' => $record_row->getField('Price_per_week'),
   );
   array_push($PaymentOrderItems, $Item); //this line is the culprit - if I comment this this out
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: How big is that data that you are are trying to store in memory in this array? Are you running into memory allocation limits?  What errors do you see in your logs?

Comment: A 500 error has to do with the server. It usually occurs when the server is not configured correctly, or if there is a syntax error in for example `.htaccess`, `httpd.ini` or `php.ini` files. It should not have anything to do with PHP code.

Comment: @Mike Brant, im only evisaging around 60 tops. My test data only has 3 though.

Comment: @JK36 I meant what is the size of data (like in KB, MB, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code appears fine. I'm assuming you've already verify the validity of the result collection?

If not, then it sounds like it may be results related. Is the data structure being returned as you're expecting?

Answer (score 4):

There is one missing `)` at the end of your foreach :

```
foreach($resultBookings->getRecords() as $key=>$record_row {
```

becomes :

```
foreach($resultBookings->getRecords() as $key=>$record_row) {
```

Comment: Yes, the parse error creates an HTTP 500 response if PHP is configured to a production environment.

Comment: Thanks, added the ending ")" on my foreach loop.It is in my original code - so its not the problem, just the code got messed up when I was trying to format it in Stack Overflow. I've now updated my original code.

Comment: Your code is OK. Check out @JamesD answer and check if there isn't a problem with the data structure. And check your logs, your apache error.log should contain the error with more precisions.

Answer (score 1):

The [array_push() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) already explains that it has the same effect as:

```
$PaymentOrderItems[] = $Item;
```